# release notes and language in Google Play Console

Tags: android, localization, google-play, release

I am updating an app and I have some new release notes for the new features.

During the publishing process Google has introduced a new way to add text for more then one language at the time. This is a good new feature but also confusing.

The release notes are done with a kind of XML Structure. For example the following is prepared by default in my case:

```
<en-US>
english release notes.
</en-US>
<de-DE>
german release notes.
</de-DE>
```

If the app is visible to british users, do they also see the text for `<en-US>` or do I have to add the english text for every specific country ?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily generate the XML structure for all languages you need with three clicks with the following application:
https://androidreleasenotes.com/

You can simply enter your own release notes. These will be translated automatically and you get the xml structure.

Comment: Requires subscription.

Comment: There are different subscriptions for the other functionalities of the tool "AppStoreManager". The functionality to create the android release notes structure in different languages is free of charge. It only needs a registration, no subscription.

Comment: You can find a list of the languages to use in the tags without registration here: 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844778?hl=en#zippy=%2Cview-list-of-available-languages

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Which means based on your device local it will consider appropriate tag inside release notes and will load only that notes in respective translated format.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to British users or any kind of users it depends on the user's phone language, what is the default language that the user is using in his mobile. so if the user was Indian and living in Canada but he uses Russian language in his phone. and you added Russian release notes. Russian release notes will appear to him. if you didn't added Russian release notes then the play store chose the default which is English

Answer (score 0):

Users with language set to "en-GB" (ie British english users) I believe will see the en-GB if it is available, otherwise they will see any other English variant (ie en-US), and then fall back to the default language,